# Update site Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony-2

bom dia.

Estou modificando um site feito em Symfony2 e estou com dificuldades na edição de conteúdo. 
Se tiro um dos arquivos .twig do servidor que corresponde ao index ou a uma das partes do site, ele para de funcionar, ou não carrega, como o esperado. Mas se modificado o conteúdo ou incluo algo, o site não é modificado.

Gostaria de saber se é necessário fazer alguma configuração a mais, limpar o cache do symfony, ou algo do tipo.

É o primeiro projeto que pego em symfony, por isso não tenho muita familiaridade com o framework, e o site está hospedado em um servidor linux, com acesso ssh.

Answer (score 0):

Após modificar o arquivo, limpe o cache usando o [console](http://symfony.com/doc/current/console/usage.html):

```
php bin/console cache:clear --env=prod
```

Cada ambiente (env) possui uma configuração de cache então, por padrão, o ambiente de desenvolvimento não precisa de limpeza a cada modificação de template.

Atente para o fato que onde escrevi `--env=prod` você precisa definir em qual ambiente (environment) está.

Comment: Obrigado pelo resposta. Tentei usar o código, mas deu uma resposta de erro. "Could not open input file: bin/console"

Comment: dependendo a versão de SF que você tem, o console está na raiz do projeto. Procure pelo arquivo

Comment: Depois que fiz isso, usando o app/console na raiz do projeto, o site saiu do ar, com erro 500. :(

Comment: O procedimento está correto. Se o site está com erro, existia algum problema inserido desde a ultima vez que o SF fez o cache.